# LDAP client for twisted

Tags: python, ldap, twisted, python-ldap

I am looking for an LDAP client for twisted. Google returns two ldaptor repos in Github, one by [antong](https://github.com/antong/ldaptor), and another by [tv42](https://github.com/tv42/ldaptor). repos has not been updated for over an year and 11 months respectively. tv42 even mentions that this repo is *Mostly of historical interest.*

So my question is whether to go with either of the repos or is there any other frequently maintained LDAP client library for twisted?

with regards,
raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these repositories are in need of some maintenance.  Whichever you choose, you should get involved with the community and help work on them, fixing bugs and updating the code.

Be aware, however, that the license differs: Tv updated his code to be (mostly) MIT-licensed but [antong has not yet acknowledged the request that he do the same](https://github.com/antong/ldaptor/issues/10); that copy is still LGPL.  (Since antong hasn't responded yet, it's not clear if this is just because he's no longer maintaining it, or because he prefers to keep it LGPL.)

Comment: Thanks, Glyph. I will stick with Tv repo. If any bugs crop up, I will report and if possible fix them.

Comment: Thanks @RajkumarS, glad to hear it.  Good luck!